# Show Frappe Chart in Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, frappe-charts

```
<script lang="ts">
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { Chart } from 'frappe-charts';

let chartElem;

const chartData = {
    labels: ["12am-3am", "3am-6pm", "6am-9am", "9am-12am",
        "12pm-3pm", "3pm-6pm", "6pm-9pm", "9am-12am"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            name: "Some Data", type: "bar",
            values: [25, 40, 30, 35, 8, 52, 17, -4]
        },
        {
            name: "Another Set", type: "line",
            values: [25, 50, -10, 15, 18, 32, 27, 14]
        }
    ]
};

onMount(() => {
    console.log(chartElem); // always undefined... why??
    new Chart({
        parent: chartElem,
        title: "My Awesome Chart",
        data: chartData,
        type: 'axis-mixed', // or 'bar', 'line', 'scatter', 'pie', 'percentage'
        height: 250,
        colors: ['#7cd6fd', '#743ee2']
    });
});
```

```
<div bind:this={chartElem}>loading chart...</div>
```

I was trying to plot a chart in my Svelte component and above is my current code. According to the Svelte doc, `bind:this` is the way to refer to the dom node `chartElem` so that in the component code I can plot a chart onto that `div`.

But somehow I keep getting `undefined` with my `chartElem` variable. Where did I do wrong? Or Perhaps I'd need to go for a different chart library other than Frappe Chart?

[Frappe Chart](https://frappe.io/charts/docs)

[Svelte bind:this](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the way I instantiated the Frappe Chart object might be wrong. I made a few tweaks to the original code.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { onMount, onDestroy } from 'svelte';
import { Chart } from 'frappe-charts';

let chartElem;
let chart

const chartData = {
    labels: ["12am-3am", "3am-6pm", "6am-9am", "9am-12am",
        "12pm-3pm", "3pm-6pm", "6pm-9pm", "9am-12am"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            name: "Some Data", type: "bar",
            values: [25, 40, 30, 35, 8, 52, 17, -4]
        },
        {
            name: "Another Set", type: "line",
            values: [25, 50, -10, 15, 18, 32, 27, 14]
        }
    ]
};

onMount(() => {
    chart = new Chart(chartElem, {
        title: "My Awesome Chart",
        data: chartData,
        type: 'axis-mixed', // or 'bar', 'line', 'scatter', 'pie', 'percentage'
        height: 250,
        colors: ['#7cd6fd', '#743ee2']
    });
});

onDestroy(() => {
    chart = null;
});

<div bind:this="{chartElem}"></div>
```

This worked for me.

Also, worth registering the `onDestroy` lifecycle method so that the chart object can be cleaned properly.

Comment: Setting that to `null` on destroy should not matter. Nothing will be referencing the component, so its internal references will not do anything. If anything, a cleanup function should be called if this library has those.